# How do I clear what I wrote on an image in Python?

Tags: python, image, for-loop, python-imaging-library

I have this code that write strings on an image and then generates the new image.

```
counter = 0
for a, b, c, d, e in data_cap:
    # Add Text to an image
    I1.text((269, 45), f"{a}", font=myFont, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    I1.text((524, 45), f"{b}", font=myFont, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    I1.text((390.5, 121.5), f"{c}", font=myFontSmall, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    I1.text((500.9, 121.5), f"{d}", font=myFontSmall, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    I1.text((610.5, 121.5), f"{e}", font=myFontSmall, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    counter += 1
    img.save(f"car{counter}.png")
```

The problem with this code is that it writes on top of the first image generated.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Create a copy of the image, write on the copy? Use a different name when you save?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Although the name on the save part is already solved, I think.

Comment: As a hint for the future: it helps to mention the libraries you're using explicitly, both when searching and when asking.

Answer (score 0):

I included the Image.open() function in the for loop to solve the problem.
The code now looks like this:

```
counter = 0
for a, b, c, d, e in data_cap:
    img = Image.open(r'path')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((131, 45), f"{a}", font=myFont, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    draw.text((385.5, 45), f"{b}", font=myFont, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    draw.text((252.5, 121.5), f"{c}", font=myFontSmall, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    draw.text((362.9, 121.5), f"{d}", font=myFontSmall, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    draw.text((473.5, 121.5), f"{e}", font=myFontSmall, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    img.save(fr'path')
    counter += 1
```